# NEHotspotConfigurationManager error problem when the wifi not exist

Tags: ios, swift, networkextension

I found a problem when i try to connect a non-existent wifi, this is my code:

```
let configuration = NEHotspotConfiguration.init(ssid: "wifi-name")  
 NEHotspotConfigurationManager.shared.apply(configuration) { [unowned self] (error) in  
       print("NEHotspotConfigurationManager.error: \(error)")  
   }
```

if the wifi dosen't exist, i see and dialog with

> "impossible to connect network "wifi-nam""

But the error in the `NEHotspotConfigurationManager` is nil, so how can control if a specific ssid wifi exists?

Answer (score 0):

The unfortunate answer is: You can not control if a specific WiFi exists.

This is the intended behaviour. If you could check if a certain wifi is nearby, you could track a user with that information. This is why android asks for location permissions if you want to do this. On iOS this is currently simply not possible.